# Google Task Api makes Window service hang

Tags: c#, google-api, task

I am developing a window service using C# and google Task API. It works in window form and Console aplication of C#. my code sample is

```
        UserCredential credential;
        using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                new[] { TasksService.Scope.Tasks },
                "shyam.sundar525@gmail.com", CancellationToken.None, new FileDataStore("Tasks.Auth.Store")).Result;
        }            


        // Create the service.
        var service = new TasksService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "Tasks API Sample",
        });
       //creating new task
        var list = new TaskList();
        list.Title = SampleListName;
        list = service.Tasklists.Insert(list).Execute();

        service.Tasks.Insert(new Task { Title = "Learn the Task API" }, list.Id).Execute();
        service.Tasks.Insert(new Task { Title = "Implement a WP application using Task API" }, list.Id).Execute();
```

When i run window service in Taskbar, It makes hang.Service is neither stop not running only show starting.
Thanks 
shyams